# memcache(d) does not work on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached, xubuntu

I'm trying to use memcache on my apache. (Xubuntu 13.10)
I installed Apache 2.4, Php5, Mysql5, php pear etc like here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-12-04

php -m

```
root@benjamin:~# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
memcache
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

ps aux

```
root@benjamin:~# ps aux | grep memcached
www-data 16113  0.0  0.0 325400   916 ?        Ssl  12:10   0:00 memcached -d -m 128 -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -vv -u www-data
root     16178  0.0  0.0  18008   956 pts/1    S+   12:16   0:00 grep --color=auto memcached
```

and sample php code that i use

```
<?php 
  $memcache = new Memcache;
  $memcache->connect("localhost",11211); # You might need to set "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"
  echo "Server's version: " . $memcache->getVersion() . "<br />\n";
  $tmp_object = new stdClass;
  /*
  $tmp_object->str_attr = "test";
  $tmp_object->int_attr = 123;
  $memcache->set("key",$tmp_object,false,50);
  */
  $stat = $memcache->getExtendedStats();
  echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br />\n";
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($stat);

   echo "Data from the cache:<br />\n";

  print_r($memcache->get("key"));

?>
```

Problem is, nothing happens. Totally white page. How can i achive this?
P.S : I also tried to connect 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Update, I configured php.ini and I can get error now.

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/memcache.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: I've just installed memcached and the php5 module - and it just works. If you are having trouble, My first suggestion is to put full error-reporting on, with "error_reporting(-1);" at the top of the script, while debugging at least.

Comment: Hello Alister, i wrote error_reporting(-1); and still white page.

Comment: I configured php.ini, now I can get errors.

Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/memcache.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You have appear to have the PHP module memcache enabled for the CLI version, but not for Apache. Create a phpinfo() page, see if it is listed. If not, restart Apache and try again, otherwise, make sure it's being loaded in /etc/php5/apache/*

Comment: phpinfo();

http://i.imgur.com/WTi9CIP.png where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej bencagri,

make sure you have installed php5-memcache, (php5-memcached if you areon debian).

create a phpinfo.php file and write

```
<?php
 echo phpinfo();
?>
```

and have memcache, if you can't find anything, you'll have to

```
sudo a2enmod mem_cache
```

module in apache2.

restart your apache and try again.

Patrick

Comment: Hello Pattrick, I did it, and it says php5-memcache is already installed, php5-memcached is now being installed. But sudo a2enmod mem_cache says "ERROR: Module mem_cached does not exist!" and tried sudo a2enmod memcache, this one is same,too. Edit, i can also see memcache library on phpinfo();

Comment: a2enmod enables the apache module - not PHP.

Comment: i used a from scratch installed debian, installed apache2, php5, php5-memchache, php5-memchached and memcachedb. after that i tried your script from above and got also a white page. after this i a2enmod mod_cache and restart apache, then it woked for me. it only Update: worked with 127.0.0.1.